# block from installing network-manager

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

How can I, for always, block the installation of a package? (in this case: `network-manager`)

I previously did

```
echo network-manager hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

After some update I found that it was installed again.
How Can I get it to stay blocked?

Comment: Just some advice: lay of the CAPS and the bold an the exlamation points. Just ask your question.

Comment: thanks for advice, but i'm REALLY PISSED OFF, and already i'm tring hard not to say something really bad about that package and don't get the subject changed to what it does good or bad, i just want to never see it again in my system instead of trying to fix it every time ... also thanks for editing, and i hope i get an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look [at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

It has a highly upvoted answer supposing to do what you want. I'd not consider it a duplicate (it is about not updating), but nevertheless you should check out that answer.
Did you uninstall etc beforehand? These commands will probably not remove a current installation. Did you check if it is removed after uninstalling (some leftover files could make it look like your package is still there)?
After that, be sure to run those commands with `SUDO`.

The `dpkg` solution should work.

If that doens't work, there are some other methods as well. For instance from [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/91420/how-do-i-block-a-deb-file-from-being-installed-as-the-result-of-a-dependency)

> put the following into your /etc/apt/preferences:

```
Package: i-am-a-package-containing-junk
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

> the Pin-Priority: -1 says that the matched versions of the matched packages should never be installed, while the rest matches every version of the package i-am-a-package-containing-junk, effectively preventing its installation.

Finally, you might take a look [on this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-apt-get-blacklisting-packages-using-hold-option/): it shows you the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove`, and how to use it.

Comment: thank you, that did the trick, now even if i try to install it (apt-get install network-manager) i cannot, really thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages about the `--set-selection` option:

> Note  that  this  will  not actually install or remove anything, but
>   just set the selection state on the requested packages. You will need
>   some other application to actually download and install the requested
>   packages. For example, run `apt-get dselect-upgrade`.

Also, have you tried unistalling it with `apt-get` ?

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

Comment: yes, i did remove it with apt-get remove, but it got re-installed all by itself after an update